# Pass Json data object from view containing partial view in MVC4

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

I am creating an MVC4 Form for person.
I have these Partial Views containing Information about Contact Info and Postal Address.

**ContactInfo.cshtml**

```
@model Demo.Models.ContactInfo
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/plugins/validationengine/css/validationEngine.jquery.css" />

    <h2>ContactInfo</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-4">PhoneNumber</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-4">CellNumber</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CellNumber)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Email</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
</div>
```

**PostalAddress.cshtml**

```
@model Demo.Models.PostalAddress
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/plugins/validationengine/css/validationEngine.jquery.css" />
<h2>PostalAddress</h2>
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-lg-4">CountryID</label>
   <div class="col-lg-4">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CountryID)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">CityID</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CityID)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">ProvinceID</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProvinceID)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">ZipCode</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ZipCode)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">StreetAddress</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StreetAddress)
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are the Model classes for  Person,Postal Address and Contact Info.

**ContactInfo.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo.Models
{
public partial class ContactInfo
{
    public ContactInfo()
    {
        this.Branches = new List<Branch>();
        this.People = new List<Person>();
    }

    public long ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CellNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}
}
```

Here is the **Person.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo.Models
{
public partial class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        this.Branches = new List<Branch>();
        this.Documents = new List<Document>();
        this.Faculties = new List<Faculty>();
        this.Institutes = new List<Institute>();
        this.Parents = new List<Parent>();
        this.Students = new List<Student>();
        this.StudentParents = new List<StudentParent>();
        this.StudentParents1 = new List<StudentParent>();
    }

    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Gender { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DOB { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> ContactID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> PersonTypeID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> PostalAddressID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> ReligionID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
    public virtual ContactInfo ContactInfo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Faculty> Faculties { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Institute> Institutes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
    public virtual PersonType PersonType { get; set; }
    public virtual PostalAddress PostalAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual Religion Religion { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StudentParent> StudentParents { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StudentParent> StudentParents1 { get; set; }
}
}
```

**PostalAddress.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo.Models
{
public partial class PostalAddress
{
    public PostalAddress()
    {
        this.Branches = new List<Branch>();
        this.Papers = new List<Paper>();
        this.People = new List<Person>();
    }

    public long ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> CountryID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CityID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ProvinceID { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
    public virtual city city { get; set; }
    public virtual country country { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Paper> Papers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
    public virtual province province { get; set; }
}
```

}

Here is the Main **Person.cshtml**
I am rendering the upper partial views in it and sending the **json** object data back.

```
@model Demo.Models.Person
@{
 ViewBag.Title = "Person";
}

<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)    
    <legend>Person</legend>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Name</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Gender</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gender)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-4">DOB</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Photo</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Photo)
        </div>
    </div>
    @Html.Partial("ContactInfo", new Demo.Models.ContactInfo())
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-4">PersonTypeID</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            @Html.DropDownList("PersonTypeID", String.Empty)
        </div>
    </div>

    @Html.Partial("PostalAddress", new Demo.Models.PostalAddress())

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-4">ReligionID</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            @Html.DropDownList("ReligionID", String.Empty)
        </div>
    </div>

    <p>
        <input id="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
}

<script>
$('#submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //alert('hello');
    var person = {
        Name: $('#Name').val(),
        Gender: $('#Gender').val(),
        DOB: $('#DOB').val(),
        Photo: $('#Photo').val(),
        PersonTypeID: $('PersonTypeID').val(),
        ContactInfo: {
            PhoneNumber: $('#PhoneNumber').val(),
            CellNumber: $('#CellNumber').val(),
            Email: $('#Email').val()
        },
        PostalAddress: {
            CountryID: $('#CountryID').val(),
        CityID: $('#CityID').val(),
        ProvinceID: $('#ProvinceID').val(),
        ZipCode: $('#ZipCode').val(),
        StreetAddress: $('#StreetAddress').val(),
    },
    };

    var data = { jsonperson: person };
    //console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Person/Create',
        type: "post",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),

        success: function () {
            $('#message').html('person added').fadeIn();
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#message').html('person added').fadeIn();
        }
    });
```

But when i send the data from form to controller The data containing postal address and Contact info is Null.

Here is the **Person Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Create(Person jsonperson)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.People.Add(jsonperson);
        db.SaveChanges();
        //   return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.ContactID = new SelectList(db.ContactInfoes, "ID", "Email", jsonperson.ContactID);
    ViewBag.PersonTypeID = new SelectList(db.PersonTypes, "ID", "Name", jsonperson.PersonTypeID);
    ViewBag.PostalAddressID = new SelectList(db.PostalAddresses, "ID", "ZipCode", jsonperson.PostalAddressID);
    ViewBag.ReligionID = new SelectList(db.Religions, "ID", "Name", jsonperson.ReligionID);
    // return View(jsonperson);
    JsonResult jr = new JsonResult();
    jr.Data = true;
    return jr;
}
```

Data is coming to the controller but Contact Info details and Postal Address is null. It is driving me crazy .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In order to pass back (say) `PhoneNumber` for binding it needs to be passed as `ContactInfo.PhoneNumber:  $('#PhoneNumber').val(),`. But really, learn about using view models, and use `EditorTemplates` (not partials) for properties which are complex objects so they are correctly named, then you can just use `$('form').serialize();`

Comment: I know That Technique but i was kind of trying to implement it this way for education purpose @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0):

the serialized JSON data that is being passed to your controller after you submit the form, does not have any property such as *ContactId* or *PersonTypeID* etc

your controller will receive *PhoneNumber, CellNumber, Email, CountryID, CityID, ProvinceID, ZipCode, StreetAddress*

therefore your model **Person** should have the above properties as it is named in your partial view models so they can be read accordingly into your **Person** model.

Comment: I am using entity frame work and its connected with sql server .
Plus contactId is the primary key